# Whitelisting Application Gateway (WAFv2) Frontend IP results in 403 on App Service using access restrictions

Tags: azure, gateway, restriction, azure-application-gateway

My health probe fails with a 403 as soon as I apply whitelisting to the App Service configured in the backend pool (I whitelist the IP that's assigned to the application gateway. IP is a standard tier and static.

Has anyone else been seeing this issue before? I was under the impression that I could whitelist the public IP assigned to the application gateway on the App Service so access is only possible from the Application Gateway endpoint.

The health probe is successful when I remove the whitelisting. So I'm sure it has something to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-application-gateway-works#how-an-application-gateway-routes-a-request),

> If the backend pool:
>
> Is a public endpoint, the application gateway uses its frontend public
>   IP to reach the server. If there isn't a frontend public IP address,
>   one is assigned for the outbound external connectivity.
>
> **Contains an internally resolvable FQDN or a private IP address, the application gateway routes the request to the backend server by using
>   its instance private IP addresses.**
>
> Contains an external endpoint or an externally resolvable FQDN, the
>   application gateway routes the request to the backend server by using
>   its frontend public IP address. The DNS resolution is based on a
>   private DNS zone or custom DNS server, if configured, or it uses the
>   default Azure-provided DNS. If there isn't a frontend public IP
>   address, one is assigned for the outbound external connectivity.

Thus, you may use an internally resolvable FQDN or a private IP address of the backend app service in the backend pool.

In this case, you could change to use the default Azure app service hostname like `webappname.azurewebsites.net` or whitelist the internal app gateway subnet (where the application gateway instance private IP address) in the access restrictions of app service.